# Setting kermit line on command-line instead of .kermrc

Tags: kermit

I am establishing a kermit connection to my target via a ~/.kermrc file as suggested...

> set line /dev/ttyUSB0
>
> set flow-control none
>
> set carrier-watch off
>
> set speed 115200
>
> connect

... But I periodically must unpower the target, which then changes the ttyUSB enumeration, which means I need to change the USB enumeration in the ~/.kermrc file.

My question is, is there a way to dynamically populate the USB line number without modifying the ~/.kermrc. If I remove the 'set line /dev/ttyUSB' and attempt to populate via command-line like this...

> kermit -l /dev/ttyUSB0

... the ~/.kermrc file is read first and the command-line line configuration is not respected, so you receive errors that a line number must be set before setting the additional options in the ~/.kermrc.

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: I too am looking for a similar solution. I had done it through scripts though. You may take a look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133310/how-can-i-get-kermit-script-to-accept-arguments-and-connect-to-serial-device). Passing port number as argument seemed to be the best solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is infinity later but in many modern systems there are udev rules that create symlinks for serial ports

check and see if you have a `/dev/serial/by-id/` or `/dev/serial/by-path/` directory (when your usb serial is connected).  If you do inspect their content and you will see symbolic links.  I usually use
`/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_USB_Null_Modem_Cable_XXXXXXXX-if00-port0` rather than `/dev/ttyUSB0`

As for your original question - yes you can pass arguments on the commandline - just remove yoru .kermrc or just set there parameters that can be set before the `set line` command as that one actually establishes a connection.

You could theoretically remove it altogether and just use a commandline (make it a bash function?)

```
kermit -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 \
    -C "set flow-control none, set carrier-watch off"
```